# Pre-populated abstract methods

Tags: c#, abstract

I got a class who need some abstract methods to invoke LinQ expressions to get collections from which I don't know the type.

Something like this :

```
abstract List<object> Find(IEnumerable<object> items, object objectToFind)
```

So, the override method have to start to cast the objects to be able to perform LinQ query on them.

Something like that :

```
List<StrongType> things = items.Cast<StrongType>().ToList();
var thingToFind = (StrongType) objectToFind;
// <- PERFORM LINQ HERE
return result.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Everything is working fine BUT if someone else need to make another child class from the abstracted one, he can do a big mistake.

So... I just need some advices to help me maybe simplify my technique with some code and not just comments or if it's possible to had some code to force prepopulating overrided classes in Visual Studio (with attributes maybe ?).

I hope to be understood (my english is a little poor)

Thanks ;)

Comment: Is it possible to leverage generics on the base class? So instead of `Find` being typed against `object`, it would be `Find(IEnumerable<T> items, T objectToFind)`? If not, then I guess make _very clear_ documentation remarks about overriding/implementing the methods?

Comment: Yea, I used generics finally and everything works fine ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you can't use generics in abstract method or class definition?

```
abstract List<T> Find(IEnumerable<T> items, T objectToFind)
```

And then inherit your class as

```
public class Foo : Bar<StrongType>
{
   public override List<StrongType> Find(IEnumerable<StrongType> items, StrongType objectToFind)
   {
       // perform LINQ here
       return result.ToList();
   }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, the solution is just in front of you... Thanks for your answer ;)